# local week of the year in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, datepart

I have to generate year wise, weekly reports for some data. Now When I aggregate date on week number, and week number is calculated from extract from creation date.

Now the problem is these both queries return week number 52.

```
SELECT EXTRACT(WEEK FROM TIMESTAMP '2006-01-01');
SELECT EXTRACT(WEEK FROM TIMESTAMP '2006-12-31');
```

First query return 52 (52nd week of 2005) and 2nd query return 52 (52nd week of year 2006). thats documented behavior.

But I want to Calculate local week number, and results for first query should be 1 and other query would return 53.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do this with the `exctract()` function, it only supports ISO weeks.

But the `to_char()` function has [an option](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-DATETIME-TABLE) for this:

```
SELECT to_char(DATE '2006-01-01', 'WW')::int` --> 1
SELECT to_char(DATE '2006-12-31', 'WW')::int` --> 53
```

Answer (score 0):

For date `2006-01-01` end week is start in `2005` year, that same problem is 1999 year. 
Clausule `EXTRACT(WEEK` getting year where week is started not ending.

You can use this code:

```
SELECT floor(EXTRACT(doy FROM TIMESTAMP '2006-01-01')/7 + 1);

SELECT floor(EXTRACT(doy FROM TIMESTAMP '2006-12-31')/7 + 1);
```